# Como exibir o id como contador de formulário

Tags: php, mysql

Estou criando um contador de formulário e gostaria de saber se estou indo no caminho certo ?

Essa é minha query de select

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

//Criar a conexao
$link = new mysqli ("localhost", "root", "", "peixaria");
if($link->connect_errno){
     echo"Nossas falhas local experiência ..";
     exit();
}



         $sql= "SELECT MAX(m.id_pedido)
                FROM mpedido as m WHERE id_pedido
                ORDER BY m.id_pedido DESC
                LIMIT 1";
        $resultado_id= mysqli_query($link,$sql);

?>
```

e essa é o código php que exibir o id como contador . mas tipo está dando um erro

> Notice: Array to string conversion in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Projetos\pedidos.php on line 61

```
  <span>Comanda:</span>
                    <?php


                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_id)){
                echo '<span>'.["id_pedido"].'</span>';

                }

                ?>
```

Como eu poderia fazer um contador a partir do id

Comment: Me parece uma duplicata de: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/178905/como-criar-um-campo-contador-em-php-a-partir-do-id-da-tabela

Comment: Pois é ninguém soube responder

Comment: Sinto que todas suas perguntas acabam sendo mal respondidas ou então nem respondidas são... sugiro que de uma lida no tópico [ask] e faca um [tour]

Comment: Na verdade ate onde vejo, todas suas perguntas poderiam se enquadrar na sinalização de "não esta claro o suficientemente"

Comment: Um sei como que é .

Comment: `echo '<span>'.["id_pedido"].'</span>';` você está tornando o `id_pedido` em um array quando coloca entre colchetes. Use `$row['id_pedido']` para mostrar o ID.

Comment: **Array to string conversion** quer dizer que você está mandando imprimir um array como se fosse uma string. Quando houver esse tipo de erro, troque o `echo` por `print_r` para 'debugar' a linha do erro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O erro está em:

```
echo '<span>'.["id_pedido"].'</span>';
```

*Isso não existe.*

Quando se usa o código:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_id)){

}
```

Está dizendo que enquanto houver o linhas, você irá obter a array `$row`, ou seja deveria de se utilizar:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_id)){

 echo '<span>'.$row["id_pedido"].'</span>';

}
```

**Mas... Isso não irá funcionar também.** A razão disso é que não existe o índice `id_pedido` e o motivo de não existir é porque não há isso definido no `SELECT`.

---

> Você não precisa usar o `while()` se o houver o `LIMIT 1`, se o limite é 1 ele irá executar apenas uma vez.

---

### Correções possíveis:

**Método 0. Use index numérico:**

Parte do While:

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_id);
echo '<span>'.$row[0].'</span>';
```

**Método 1. Dê nome aos bois:**

Parte do Query:

```
$sql= "SELECT MAX(m.id_pedido) as ultimo FROM mpedido as m WHERE id_pedido ORDER BY m.id_pedido DESC LIMIT 1";

$resultado_id= mysqli_query($link,$sql);
```

Logo, agora o `SELECT` possui um resultado com o nome `ultimo` para o resultado do `MAX(m.id_pedido)`, que é mais fácil.

Parte do While:

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_id);
echo '<span>'.$row['ultimo'].'</span>';
```

Comment: ele vai mostrar o id certo ,? mas tipo toda vez que eu abrir um novo formulário , ele vai exibir o id do formulário anterior e como faço pra dar um incremento +1 pra ele mostrar o id do formulário que está sendo preenchido ?

Comment: Use `$row['ultimo'] + 1`, irá acrescentar 1 ao número. Mas, existe um problema de lógica aí, se duas pessoas abrirem a página vão ver o mesmo número de próximo, sendo que se ambos enviarem somente um dele terá tal número.

Comment: Muito Obrigado .

Comment: Olá @Inkeliz , bem utilizei esse código ele tá mostrando o id anterior ao clicar no novo formulario como faço pra acrescentar um valor a mais assim ele mostra o id que será inserido no formulário .

Answer (score 2):

Bem sei se entendi bem, mas acredito que você queira algo como:

```
//Criar a conexao
$link = new mysqli ("localhost", "root", "", "peixaria");
if($link->connect_errno){
 echo"Nossas falhas local experiência ..";
 exit();
}   

$sql= "SELECT MAX(m.id_pedido) as ultimo_id FROM mpedido as m";
$resultado_id= mysqli_query($link,$sql);
?>
```

Como você utilizou o MAX(), ele irá retornar o maior valor do campo id_pedido, logo se este for um campo sequencial ele já irá retornar o valor desejado.

Já no php você deverá fazer assim

```
<span>Comanda:</span>
<?php
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_id)){
   echo '<span>'.$row["ultimo_id"].'</span>';
  }
```

?>

Quando você faz este while, recebe uma linha com a informação retornada, porém ela vem como array, logo você precisa acessar o índice que você criou no SQL, no caso "ultimo_id".

Espero que seja isso o que procura.

Comment: eu quero que ele mostre o ultimo_id e acrescente mais um nele assim na tela mostrará o id do formulário aberto e que será inserido .

Comment: Você poderá fazer assim no sql:     $sql= "SELECT MAX(m.id_pedido)+1 as ultimo_id FROM mpedido as m";

Comment: Muito Obrigado mano